# Recursion bracketed; or Dyck words generation

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, combinatorics, balanced-string

We already have challenges to [check if a string of brackets is fully matched](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77138/48022) and to [count the number of balanced strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66127/48022). It remains for us to generate these strings, but it will not be so easy…

A Dyck word is a string, of length *2n*, consisting of *n* opening and *n* closing parentheses (`(` and `)`) fully matched (that is to say: for all prefixes of the string, the number of opening parentheses is greater than or equal to the number of closing ones).

It is interesting to note that the number of different Dyck words of length *2n* is equal to the *(n + 1)*-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

It’s pretty straightforward to write a program that generates these words with a recursive function. But the goal here is to do the same thing without.

## Challenge

Write a full program or function that takes a positive integer, *n*, using `stdin` or an acceptable alternative, and outputs all the different Dyck words of length *2n*. The words can appear in any order and each must be separated from each other by a line break. Moreover, your program should not use recursive functions (see details below).

### Rules

- The output of your program should only contain Dyck words of length *2n*, separated by line breaks. Each word must appear only once.
- Your program must work at minimum for inputs 0 to 15.
- You may not write recursive functions, neither direct (a function that calls itself) nor indirect (e.g. a function *f* that calls another function *g* that calls function *f*). That being said, you can still use the standard functions of your language without worry of how they work internally.
- Similarly, your program should not call itself.
- You may not use non-standard librairies.
- Your program may not read or write files.
- Your program must be able to run in a reasonable time for *0 ≤ n ≤ 15* (hence, naively generate all arrangements is probably not a good idea). Let’s say less than 20 minutes with a memory limit of 4 GB (my reference implementation in C manages *n = 15* in less than 5 seconds).
- [All standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/48022) are forbidden.

As usual in [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins. But if you have found an interesting way to achieve this challenge in your language, please do not hesitate.

## Test I/O

For this input:

```
3
```

The output could be (any other order is correct too):

```
((()))
()()()
(()())
(())()
()(())
```

Comment: I think you need to define recursion better. You can easily build your own function with `goto` statements, stacks in loops, etc. I don't think this kind of exclusion will ever work nicely for a challenge, as any approach to do this could be argued to be some form of implementing recursion yourself?

Comment: This is a very interesting challenge. but most of the rules make it worse. For example `You may not write recursive functions` Why not? `Similarly, your program should not call itself.` Why not? `Your program may not read or write files.` Submissions are unlikely to, but why not? That also goes against our [default allowed IO methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Also, it is standard to allow functions rather than just full programs.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes, it is still possible to emulate the recursion. But it is penalized by the place that takes this “emulation”. The goal is not to prohibit all forms of recursion, just make it more difficult (bracket it ;-]). So I see two valid approaches: circumvent the ban, or do completely differently.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan As I said, the goal is to make harder to use a recursive principle. Although, as noted above, it is still possible. All cited rules are designed with that in mind. Regarding the remark on functions rather than full programs, it seems perfectly acceptable, I will add it.

Comment: I think you may be falling into the trap of [assuming languages are all similar](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8067/31625). I think as it stands this challenge is too broad, as I will be totally uncertain as to what would count as valid "emulation" of recursion vs the banned actual recursion, in say stack based languages.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman It came to my mind while writing the challenge. That's why the challenge does not prohibit all forms of recursion. It just does not allow to write recursive functions. If the concept of functions does not exist in the selected language, or if recursion is underlying, the answer seems valid to me.

Comment: Using an approach which builds the strings one character at a time and then filters them (so it generates at most twice as many strings as Dyke paths), I'm running out of memory with a 2GB heap for `n=15`. I can get `n=14` in 3m41s with a 2GB heap.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, doubling the time taken is only reasonable if the reference implementation is in a slow high-level language, unless the intention is to exclude high-level languages. See e.g. [my question on practical numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24258/194) for an example of what I consider reasonable: that allowed taking 250 times as long as my reference Java answer, and 10 times as long as my reference Python answer.

Comment: @mlpo Oh, whoops, don't mind me I'm bad at using my calculator :P Anyway, then how long does it take? Try using Peter's guidelines along with your own solution to come up with something reasonable.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman With an old PC, my solution takes less than 5 seconds in C.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for your advices. I have set the limit at 20 minutes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor My solution has a small memory footprint, but I do not want to disqualify other approaches. I increased the limit to 4 GB.

Comment: This challenge hits too many [things to avoid](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8047/20260): [Needless fluff](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9384/20260) with the extra conditions, [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260) and [disadvantaging functional languages](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8058/20260) by [patching out](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8943/20260) recursion, [chameleon challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260) with the minor-seeming time/space requirement actually being a big limitation.

Comment: For a first challenge, I think you're off to a good start, but in the future I recommend less micromanaging requirements.

Comment: It appears no one has pointed out [the sandbox yet](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478). For future challenges, I recommend giving it a try: you post a challenge specification there instead of here and can get feedback and iron out some of the details before the challenge goes live and people start working on/answering it. That can help avoid a lot of frustration for everyone and often results in an overall better challenge.

Comment: Thank you both for your constructive comments. I did not know the sandbox, thank you for the information, I’ll use it next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
jeuaGsMs*VjRL`()_GGQ]]k
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jeuaGsMs%2aVjRL%60%28%29_GGQ%5D%5Dk&input=3)

```
                    ]]k   starting at G=[['']],
  u                Q      repeat the given number of times:
                _G          reversed G
          jRL`()            parenthesize each level-2 element
        *V        G         take Cartesian products of corresponding
                              elements of that and G
       s                    concatenate, yielding a list of pairs
     sM                     concatenate each resulting pair
   aG                       append the resulting list to G
je                        finally, join the last result on newlines
```

This directly follows the [Catalan recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties) (with a non-recursive dynamic programming implementation) and doesn’t use any filtering.  On my laptop, it runs in 55 seconds using 2.67 GiB RAM for *n* = 15.

## Pyth, 33 bytes, *O*(*n*) memory

```
=S*Q`()Wn2J+3x
Q"(()"=+.<S<QJ1>QJ
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3DS%2aQ%60%28%29Wn2J%2B3x%0AQ%22%28%28%29%22%3D%2B.%3CS%3CQJ1%3EQJ&input=3)

```
  *Q`()                  build a string with Q copies of "()"
 S                       sort it
=                        assign it to Q

       W                 while the following is true:
(newline)                  print Q
Q
             x             take the index of the first occurrence of "(()"
 "(()"
           +3              add 3
          J                assign to J
        n2                 is this not equal to 2 (i.e. was "(()" found)?
                         do the following:
           <QJ             take the first J characters of Q
          S                sort them
        .<    1            cyclically shift them left by 1
       +       >QJ         add the remaining characters of Q
      =                    assign to Q
```

This algorithm outputs all Dyck words in a stream, with each word being generated from the previous one and no additional state.  On my laptop, it runs in 170 seconds using basically no RAM for *n* = 15.

As an example illustrating how it works:

```
()()()()((()()(())))(())
         ^^^               becomes
(((((()))))(()(())))(())
```

Similarly computing the words in the reverse of this order also takes 33 bytes:

```
=*QK`()WJhx
Q_K=+t.iFc2_<QJ+K>QhJ
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3D%2aQK%60%28%29WJhx%0AQ_K%3D%2Bt.iFc2_%3CQJ%2BK%3EQhJ&input=3)

Comment: Nice answer! Well done for the generation of a word from the previous one, it was also the spirit of my solution.

Answer (score 6):

## C99, 105 bytes

```c
i,j,s;f(n){for(char a[31]={};++i%(1<<2*n);s||puts(a))for(j=s=0;~s&&j<2*n;)s+=1-(a[j]=40+(i>>j++)%2)%2*2;}
```

Iterates over all strings of **2n** parentheses.

With piped output and compiler flag `-O3`, input **n = 15** takes roughly *15.5 seconds* on my machine. Memory consumption is 1.2 MB.

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/rBOtAV).

Comment: It takes a bit more than 1 minute here. This answer seems valid. It is possible to have a more efficient approach than generate all arrangements, but I'm not sure that it is shorter to write.

Comment: Well, I precisely chose C because I thought I could get away with a brute-force approach, and I wasn't disappointed. The last edit (125 to 124) doubles the run time by the way.

Comment: Breaking out of the inner loop as soon as there's an unmatched `)` lowered the run time to one fourth *and* reduced the byte count.

Answer (score 5):

### CJam (48 bytes)

```
ri"()"*${_p_,{1$>_)-,\(-,<},_{W=/(\s$1m>+}{&}?}h
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%22()%22*%24%7B_p_%2C%7B1%24%3E_)-%2C%5C(-%2C%3C%7D%2C_%7BW%3D%2F(%5Cs%241m%3E%2B%7D%7B%26%7D%3F%7Dh&input=4). This effectively takes one obvious recursive solution and makes it iterative. Instead of actually simulating the steps back up the stack, it applies a successor rule:

> Find the last `(` which starts a suffix with strictly more `)` than `(`; sort that suffix, and rotate once.

Note that this is deliberately designed to avoid keeping the full list of solutions in memory, because I don't think it fits (at least, not if run on a 64-bit machine. It might on a 32-bit machine). There are `9694845` Dyck paths for `n=15`, so that's `30*9694845` characters, and `92*9694845 = 891925740` bytes of memory just for the (Java) String objects. But then the `List` holding the objects probably wraps an array with space for `16777216` elements, which is a further 256MB, and the CJam interpreter itself seems to add quite a bit of overhead.

---

#### (42 bytes)

```
Ma{{_'(+\')+}%{"()"\f{\-,}I+_$=},}ri:I2**,
```

This builds the strings up one character at a time, filtering to ensure that no string has more than `n` opening parentheses or more closing than opening parentheses. However, it runs out of memory with 3GB for `n=15`.

The same idea at 39 bytes, but this runs out of memory earlier.

```
Ma{"()":Sm*::+{S\f{\-,}I+_$=},}ri:I2**`
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Ma%7B%22()%22m*%3A%3A%2B%7B%24I%3E'(%26!%7D%2C%7B%24_%2C(2%2F%3D'(%3D%7D%2C%7Dri%3AI2**%60&input=4)

---

#### (24 bytes)

My original answer, now disqualified by rule changes.

```
{"()"*e!{0\+{~_}*]1&!},}
```

This is an anonymous function which takes input on the stack. [Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=4%0A%0A%7B%22()%22*e!%7B0%5C%2B%7B~_%7D*%5D1%26!%7D%2C%7D%0A%0A~%60).

It works by the obvious approach of taking all permutations of `n` pairs of parentheses and filtering for those which are balanced.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this answer does not meet the seventh rule. I can not run the code in a reasonable time for n ≥ 10.

Comment: @mlpo "Reasonable" is extremely subjective. To make that rule enforcable, you should specify time and memory limits.

Comment: @Dennis Yes indeed, done. But anyway, I can not get any output for n ≥ 10, even after 10 minutes, which is logical, the algorithm is exponential.

Comment: @mlpo, online demos are always only for really small test cases. Running it locally on my 4-year-old computer, it computes `n=12` in 3m13s, although it does run out of memory with a 1GB heap on `n=13`. I'm currently testing an alternative approach which seems like it should be less brute force but is actually turning out to be much slower. I'm not entirely sure what to make of "*the algorithm is exponential*". The output is exponential. No sub-exponential answer could meet spec!

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, it is certain that we can go further with something else than a JavaScript interpreter ;-). Regarding the complexity, yes the algorithm is necessarily exponential (as the output). Thus, we must find a way to limit the number of operations performed, generate all the arrangements is not a good idea to do that ;-).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm not too sure n=12 in 3m13s means fulfilling the criteria. My solution in pyth ran n=12 in 22s on my machine, but n=15 about 18minutes.

Comment: @busukxuan, yes, but that version was written before the criteria, and it took me a while to beat the criteria and update the answer.

Comment: `ri"()"*${_p_"(()"#)_{2+/($(+\+s}{*}?}h` (port of Anders' Pyth implementation which uses a mirror-image successor rule)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 125 bytes

```
n=>{for(i=m=1<<n+n-1;i&m;i++){for(j=m,z=o=0;o>=z;j>>=1)i&j?o++:z++;o-n||console.log(i.toString(2).replace(/./g,d=>")("[d]))}}
```

Actually printing the results slows things down horribly, but with `console.log` set to `()=>{}` this takes my machine about 7 seconds for n=12, which presumably translates to 7 minutes for n=15. If that's not fast enough, you can replace `i++` with `i+=2` or even `i+=j||2` but that made only a few percent difference in my testing. Works by generating all 2n-digit binary numbers and checking whether they represent a Dyck word. Ungolfed:

```
function dyck(n) {
    // Don't bother generating words that begin with ),
    // so start half-way though 4 ** n.
    for (var i = 4 ** n / 2; i < 4 ** n; i += 2) {
        // Convert to the string of ()s.
        var word = i.toString(2);
        word = word.replace(/1/g, "(");
        word = word.replace(/0/g, ")");
        // Count the (s and )s separately.
        var left = 0;
        var right = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < n + n; j++) {
            if (word[j] == "(") left++;
            else right++;
            // Abort if there are too many )s
            if (right > left) break;
        }
        // If we got exactly n (s then it's a Dyck word.
        if (left == n) console.log(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>748</s> <s>746</s> 651 bytes

```
#define C(v,n) for(v=n==D;v<=(n<=D);v++)
void p(Z){unsigned long long R,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D=Z*2,E,F;C(C,30)C(B,29)C(A,28)C(z,27)C(y,26)C(x,25)C(w,24)C(v,23)C(u,22)C(t,21)C(s,20)C(r,19)C(q,18)C(p,17)C(o,16)C(n,15)C(m,14)C(l,13)C(k,12)C(j,11)C(i,10)C(h,9)C(g,8)C(f,7)C(e,6)C(d,5)C(c,4)C(b,3)C(a,2){R=C<<29|B<<28|A<<27|z<<26|y<<25|x<<24|w<<23|v<<22|u<<21|t<<20|s<<19|r<<18|q<<17|p<<16|o<<15|n<<14|m<<13|l<<12|k<<11|j<<10|i<<9|h<<8|g<<7|f<<6|e<<5|d<<4|c<<3|b<<2|a<<1;if(__builtin_popcount(R)!=Z)goto X;F=0;for(E=D-1;E;E--)if(R&1<<E)F++;else if(F)F--;else goto X;for(;E<D;E++)putchar(40+!(R&1<<D-E-1));puts("");X:;}}
```

At a whopping >600 bytes, this isn't really much of a contender...but it's pretty fast and memory efficient.

Works by encoding the parentheses strings as integers, with a set bit representing `(` and an unset bit representing `)`. For instance, `(())` would be `1100`. I made the following observations:

- All permutations must begin with `(` and end with `)`; otherwise, it won't be valid.
- Every valid permutation must have `n` left parentheses and `n` right parentheses, where `n` is the input number. I used `__builtin_popcount` for this.

When built via `icc -march=native -O3`, it takes 17s on my computer, though others have reported better times (~3-7s) on their (presumably faster) computers. In addition, it uses around 1.5 KB of memory.

Here's the code with explanatory comments:

```
// Z is the input number.
void p(Z){
    // All the variables.
    // R is the resulting paren number, with 1 bits for open parens and 0s for closed ones.
    // a-C are used to hold the state of each paren (1 if open, 0 if closed).
    // D holds Z*2, or the total length of the paren string.
    // E and F are used later on.
    unsigned long long R,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D=Z*2,E,F;
    /* Each loop performs a basic check. If D is equal to the corresponding
       number, then the variable will start at 1 (since the first paren must
       always be open). If D is greater than or equal to the number, then the loop
       will only be run once with the variable set to 0, and a later check will
       cause the variable to be ignored. Otherwise, it will loop twice; one for a
       closed paren (0), and one for an open one (1). Of course, if D == the
       number, then it will only loop for the open paren (as stated above). */
    for (C = (D == 30); C <= (30 <= D); C++)
    for (B = (D == 29); B <= (29 <= D); B++)
    for (A = (D == 28); A <= (28 <= D); A++)
    for (z = (D == 27); z <= (27 <= D); z++)
    for (y = (D == 26); y <= (26 <= D); y++)
    for (x = (D == 25); x <= (25 <= D); x++)
    for (w = (D == 24); w <= (24 <= D); w++)
    for (v = (D == 23); v <= (23 <= D); v++)
    for (u = (D == 22); u <= (22 <= D); u++)
    for (t = (D == 21); t <= (21 <= D); t++)
    for (s = (D == 20); s <= (20 <= D); s++)
    for (r = (D == 19); r <= (19 <= D); r++)
    for (q = (D == 18); q <= (18 <= D); q++)
    for (p = (D == 17); p <= (17 <= D); p++)
    for (o = (D == 16); o <= (16 <= D); o++)
    for (n = (D == 15); n <= (15 <= D); n++)
    for (m = (D == 14); m <= (14 <= D); m++)
    for (l = (D == 13); l <= (13 <= D); l++)
    for (k = (D == 12); k <= (12 <= D); k++)
    for (j = (D == 11); j <= (11 <= D); j++)
    for (i = (D == 10); i <= (10 <= D); i++)
    for (h = (D == 9); h <= (9 <= D); h++)
    for (g = (D == 8); g <= (8 <= D); g++)
    for (f = (D == 7); f <= (7 <= D); f++)
    for (e = (D == 6); e <= (6 <= D); e++)
    for (d = (D == 5); d <= (5 <= D); d++)
    for (c = (D == 4); c <= (4 <= D); c++)
    for (b = (D == 3); b <= (3 <= D); b++)
    for (a = (D == 2); a <= (2 <= D); a++) {
        /* R is the result here. Each variable is shifted and bitwise-ORd with the
           others to generate a number representing the string.

           For instance, (()) would be 1100, and ()(()) would be 101100. */
        R=C<<29|B<<28|A<<27|z<<26|y<<25|x<<24|w<<23|v<<22|u<<21|t<<20|s<<19|r<<18|
          q<<17|p<<16|o<<15|n<<14|m<<13|l<<12|k<<11|j<<10|i<<9|h<<8|g<<7|f<<6|
          e<<5|d<<4|c<<3|b<<2|a<<1;
        // If there is an uneven balance of parens, then just jump to the loop end.
        if(__builtin_popcount(R)!=Z) goto X;
        // F here is the number of opening parens.
        F=0;
        // E is a counter used to extract each bit.
        for(E=D-1;E;E--)
            // If the bit is set, then increment the number of open parens.
            if(R&1<<E) F++;
            // If the bit wasn't set, then decrement the number of open parens...
            else if(F) F--;
            // ...but, if there were no open parens, then it's unbalanced; jump to the end
            else goto X;
        // E (the bit counter) is already 0.
        // Loop through each bit...
        for(;E<D;E++)
            /* ...and print it out. 40 is the ASCII code for `(`. If the bit
               is set, the ! will negate it, and 0 will be added to the `(`.
               Otherwise, it will turn the left paren into a right paren. */
            putchar(40+!(R&1<<D-E-1));
        // Newline.
        puts("");
        // End of loop.
        X:;
    }
}
```

### 746-byte version

```
#define C(v,n) for(v=(n==D);v<=(n<=D);v++){
void p(Z){unsigned long long R,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D=Z*2,E,F;C(C,30)C(B,29)C(A,28)C(z,27)C(y,26)C(x,25)C(w,24)C(v,23)C(u,22)C(t,21)C(s,20)C(r,19)C(q,18)C(p,17)C(o,16)C(n,15)C(m,14)C(l,13)C(k,12)C(j,11)C(i,10)C(h,9)C(g,8)C(f,7)C(e,6)C(d,5)C(c,4)C(b,3)C(a,2)R=(C<<29)|(B<<28)|(A<<27)|(z<<26)|(y<<25)|(x<<24)|(w<<23)|(v<<22)|(u<<21)|(t<<20)|(s<<19)|(r<<18)|(q<<17)|(p<<16)|(o<<15)|(n<<14)|(m<<13)|(l<<12)|(k<<11)|(j<<10)|(i<<9)|(h<<8)|(g<<7)|(f<<6)|(e<<5)|(d<<4)|(c<<3)|(b<<2)|(a<<1);if(__builtin_popcount(R)!=Z)continue;F=0;for(E=D-1;E;E--)if(R&(1<<E))F++;else if(F)F--;else goto X;for(;E<D;E++)putchar('('+!(R&(1<<D-E-1)));puts("");X:;}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: Nice. 7 seconds here with `gcc -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -DNDEBUG`.

Comment: This is quite fast (3.5 seconds on my machine) and memory-friendly (`time` says 1.3 MB), but I'm not sure it is a serious contender in a code golf competition...

Comment: You can easily save 100 bytes by removing the `{` from the marco (only the inner loop needs it), removing the parens around the bitshifts (`|`'s predence is lower) and (with a speed hit) declaring the variables in the global scope where they'll default to `int`.

Comment: Re speed difference: Depending on which OS you use, gcc could be a lot faster (or slower) than icc.

Comment: No big deal, My JS answer ported to C is about 220, bytes 5 seconds and begligible ram use

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! I updated the code. On my computer, Clang and GCC are actually slower than Intel. What options did you use on your computer to compile it?

Comment: Just `-O3 -march=native`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 203

Implementing [this algorithm](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.2625v1.pdf) (point 3, totally iterative)

Within the limits of script executing in Firefox, I managed to have the 200K console output for input 12 in about 1.5 minutes

```js
n=>{
for(b=[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>1+2*i),z=0;!z;)
for(c=[...'('.repeat(n+n)],b.map(n=>c[n]=')'),console.log(c.join``),z=i=n;i--&&z;)
if(b[i]<n+i)for(z=0,b[j=i]++;++j<n-1;)b[j]=Math.max(b[j-1],2*j)+1
}
```

*Less golfed*

```js
n=>{
  b=[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>1+2*i)
  q=0
  for(z=0;!z;)
  {
    c=[...'('.repeat(n+n)],
    b.map(n=>c[n]=')'),
    console.log(++q,c.join``)
    for(z=i=n;i--&&z;)
      if(b[i]<n+i)
        for(z=0,b[j=i]++;++j<n-1;)
          b[j]=Math.max(b[j-1],2*j)+1
  }
}
```

**Ported to C** just for fun, run in 5 secs for input 15 (it compiles and works without #includes)

```js
f(n){int i,j,z,b[49];char c[99];
for(i=n;i--;)b[i]=2*i+1;
for(z=0;!z;){memset(c,40,n+n);c[n+n]=0;
for(i=n;i--;)c[b[i]]=41;puts(c);
for(z=i=n;i--&&z;)if(b[i]<n+i)for(z=0,b[j=i]++;++j<n;)b[j]=(b[j-1]>2*j?b[j-1]:2*j)+1;
}}
```

**Test** generating all output but do not display it, just counting output rows

I got 90 sec for input 15

```js
F=n=>{
for(b=[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>1+2*i),z=0;!z;)
for(c=[...'('.repeat(n+n)],b.map(n=>c[n]=')'),console.log(c.join``),z=i=n;i--&&z;)
if(b[i]<n+i)for(z=0,b[j=i]++;++j<n-1;)b[j]=Math.max(b[j-1],2*j)+1
}

console.log=x=>o++ // console.log display no output, just count rows

function test() {
  n=+I.value,o=0,t=+new Date
  O.textContent='...wait...'
  setTimeout(_=>(F(n),O.textContent=['rows='+o,'time sec '+(new Date-t)/1000]), 10)
  
}

test()
```

```html
N:<input id=I value=12 type=number max=20><button onclick='test()'>go</button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Really interesting solution, it may be possible to handle *n = 15* by using another approach.

Comment: In fact, I can run this function in less than 7 minutes on my machine using node. So, you just have to replace `console.log(++q,c.join``)` by `console.log(c.join``)` to have valid output and your answer is valid.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>117</s> 116 bytes

```python
def f(n):r='',;exec"r=[s+c for s in r for t in[s.count('(')]for c in')('[t+t==len(s):2-t/n]];"*2*n;print'\n'.join(r)
```

This builds the strings character by character, without filtering.

With piped output and input **n = 15**, this takes roughly 39 seconds with CPython and *7.5 seconds* with PyPy on my machine. Memory consumption is 1.6 GB with CPython and 2.5 GB with PyPy.

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/qu70hh).

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>97</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
'()'{~(,:'')((((>:#-+/)*(]#>:2*+/))"1#]),.&0,,.&1)^:(2*[)~]
```

Now tacit!

This is a monad that uses binary digits to create pairs of parentheses. In order to meet the requirements, a non-recursive approach is used along with optimization by use of certain primitives to ensure that mostly boolean (1 byte) values are used to keep memory requirements low.

On my computer, using an i7-4770k, it takes about 50 seconds to compute the result for *n* = 15 and uses about 1.5 GB of memory.

In the interests of maximizing speed, this version with **70 bytes** computes the result for *n* = 15 in 0.5 seconds while using about 800 MB of memory. It's also tacit!

```
'()'{~[:;@(<@([:,/],"1/0=|."1)/.~+/"1)<:1&(],(+/<:#-+/)"1@,.~#,.~)1$0:
```

### Usage

```
   f =: '()'{~(,:'')((((>:#-+/)*(]#>:2*+/))"1#]),.&0,,.&1)^:(2*[)~]
   timer =: 6!:2
   f 3
()()()
(())()
()(())
(()())
((()))
   10 timer 'r =: f 15'  NB. Average time over 10 runs
49.9951
   # r
9694845
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 47 bytes

```
                                                               <-empty line
Musm?<J/d\(Q?>-J/d\)0,+d\(+d\)]+d\(]+d\)G*2Q]k
```

Took 18 minutes on my machine, and over 2GB RAM.

In pythonic pseudocode:

```
// newline means "print"
M                                              map(print,
 u                                               reduce(lambda G,H:
  sm                                               sum(map(lambda d:
                     ,+d\(+d\)                       ([d+"(",d+")"] if
            ?>-J/d\)0                                   J-d.count(")") > 0
                              ]+d\(                     else [d+"("]) if
    ?<J/d\(Q                                           (J=d.count("(") < Q
                                   ]+d\)               else [d+")"],
                                        G              G)),
                                         *2Q]k     2*input(),[""]))
```

In words:

1. create a function that maps any string to a list of strings that can be formed by adding "(" or ")"
   if the parentheses are already matched, only "(" can be added; if there are already n "(", only ")" can be added; otherwise a pair is returned
2. create a new function that maps the old function over its param, and then sum up the map, so that it takes a list of strings, maps to a list of lists of strings, and then de-nests it back into a list of strings
   each call essentially "grows" its params by one `(` or `)`
3. reduce this new function over `range(2*input())`, with `[""]` as base case
   essentially just passing `[""]` through the new function 2n times
4. map `print` over the return value of `reduce` to print each string in new lines

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>111</s> 105 bytes

```
import Data.Function
id=<<fix(\h a z->id=<<[('(':)<$>h(a-1)z|a>0]++[(')':)<$>h a(z-1)|a<z]++[[""]|a+z<1])
```

Usage example: `id=<<fix(\h a z->id=<<[('(':)<$>h(a-1)z|a>0]++[(')':)<$>h a(z-1)|a<z]++[[""]|a+z<1]) $ 3` -> `["((()))","(()())","(())()","()(())","()()()"]`.

The Dyck word building algorithm used here expressed in a classic recursive way looks like

```
dyck a z =                    -- take two numbers, `a` (the number of `(` to use)
                              -- and `z` (the number of `)` to use)
                 [[""]|a+z<1] -- base case if both numbers are 0, the result
                              -- is an empty word
    [('(':)<$>dyck(a-1)z|a>0] -- if there are `(` left, prepend one to every result
                              -- from a recursive call with one `(` less
   [(')':)<$>dyck a(z-1)|a<z] -- same for `)` if there are more than `(`.
id=<<  ...  ++  ...  ++       -- combine those results in to a flat list
```

As recursion is not allowed, we pass the function to call as a third parameter `h` (and use a lambda instead of a named function):

```
\h a z ->   ....  h(a-1)z  ....  h a(z-1)
```

and let the fixpoint combinator `fix` create this function for us:

```
fix(\h a z ...)
```

finally, the leftmost `id=<<` duplicates the input parameter: `(id=<<) f n` is `f n n`, so when the whole function is called, the parameter `n` is used as `a` and `z`.

For input `15` it takes about 3min within ghci (25s when compiled) and a few MB on my 5 year old laptop.

Comment: Sorry for the unnecessary edit, I wanted to add the syntax highlighting tag to understand better what's going on, but it did not seem to work =/

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <s>140</s> 132 bytes

Thanks @nimi for saving a few bytes!

```haskell
import Data.List
h s|m<-length s=nub[k|l<-s!!0,k<-('(':l++")"):[u++v|n<-[0..m-2],u<-s!!n,v<-s!!(m-2-n)]]:s
f n=iterate h[[""]]!!n!!0
```

First of all: `iterate` does create a recursion sequecnce of `h`, but this is a builtin, and by the rules we may use builtins that use recursion.

This is just a very simple recursive approach, we can generate the n-Dyck-words by putting (n-1)-Dyck-words between paranthesis, or by concatenating from shorter Dyck words. This approach however does generate duplicates, that is why we filter for unique elements using `nub`.

As Haskell is a functional language, it is almost impossible to do this without recursion. There is an even more direct approach, but that one is banned under the current rules.

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: A few bytes to save: `f n=iterate h[[""]]!!n!!0`, `l<-s!!0`, `'(':l++")"`.

Comment: @nimi Thank you very much!