# Parentheses sequences in lexicographical order

Tags: code-golf, balanced-string

<sup>Challenge Taken from [here](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4214486/dashboard#s=p3) and also [here](https://bo.spoj.com/problems/AI_BRACK/)</sup>

An **n** parentheses sequence consists of **n** `(`s and **n** `)`s.

A valid parentheses sequence is defined as the following:

> You can find a way to repeat erasing adjacent pair of parentheses "()" until it becomes empty.
>
> For example, `(())` is a valid parentheses, you can erase the pair on the 2nd and 3rd position and it becomes `()`, then you can make it empty.
>   `)()(` is not a valid parentheses, after you erase the pair on the 2nd and 3rd position, it becomes `)(` and you cannot erase any more

**Task**

Given a number **n** you need to generate all correct parenthesis sequence in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Output can be an array, list or string (in this case a sequence per line)

You can use a different pair of parenthesis such as `{}`, `[]`, `()` or any open-close sign

**Example**

- n = 3

  ```
  ((()))    
  (()())    
  (())()    
  ()(())    
  ()()()
  ```
- n = 2

  ```
  (())
  ()()
  ```

Comment: @JoKing Yes of course. I assume that wont make any difference anyway to the main concept of the challenge.

Comment: Eh, I can think of a few languages where eval would interpret them differently for example

Comment: [Related: Catalan Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66127/catalan-number) (result of that challenge = number of lines of result of this challenge)

Comment: [Virtually the same](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83971/recursion-bracketed-or-dyck-words-generation?noredirect=1&lq=1), but with some weird restrictions like "You may not write recursive functions". /// [A superset of this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117832/generate-all-brain-flak-snippets?noredirect=1&lq=1) (allow all Brain-Flak brackets)

Comment: Does "an array, list or string" "of sequences" of "any open-close sign" mean we could output a list of lists of two integers (like `1`s and `-1`s)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan You can output a list of list but not using `1, -1`.

Comment: So what are "any open-close sign"s? Do you mean any pair of open-close characters like `<>`, `‘’` or `⁽⁾`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Exactly. Sorry if I was unclear on that

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 bytes

```perl6
{grep {try !.EVAL},[X~] <[ ]>xx$_*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAobqkqFJBUc81zNGnVic6oi5WwSZaIdauokIlXsuo9n9afpGCoZ6esUJ1cWKlgp5aWu1/AA)

Finds all lexographically sorted combinations of \$2n\$ `[]`s and filters the ones that `EVAL` correctly. Note that all valid combinations (even stuff like `[][]`) evaluate to `[]` (which is falsey, but we `not` it (`!`) to distinguish from `try` returning `Nil`)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                  }  # Anonymous code block
                        <[ ]>         # Create a list of ("[", "]")
                             xx$_*2   # Duplicate this 2n times
                   [X~]               # Find all possible combinations
 grep {          },                   # Filter from these
            .EVAL                     # The EVAL'd strings
       try !                          # That do not throw an error
```

Comment: If anyone's curious, `[][]` is the [Zen slice](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts#index-entry-Zen_slices) of an empty array which yields the array itself. The slice can be applied multiple times, so `[][][][]...` evaluates to `[]`. Besides, `[[]]` doesn't construct a nested array but an empty array because of the [single argument rule](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list#Single_Argument_Rule) (you'd have to write `[[],]` for a nested array). So any balanced sequence of `[]` brackets results in an empty array which boolifies to false.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>112</s> <s>107</s> 99 bytes

Non-recursive approach. We use "<" and ">" because it avoids escape characters in the regex. To allow us to use a shorter specification for an ASCII range, we generate 3^2n 2n-character strings of "<", "=" and ">" using `expand.grid` (via their ASCII codes 60, 61 and 62) and then grep to see which combinations give balanced open and close brackets. The "=" possibilities will get ignored, of course.

Via http://rachbelaid.com/recursive-regular-experession/

```r
function(n)sort(grep("^(<(?1)*>)(?1)*$",apply(expand.grid(rep(list(60:62),2*n)),1,intToUtf8),,T,T))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEAXQuxQX88sopkiRUuwlokuhtEkJlElIp6BePqKrt3m5@P5Y/C6Thigk2GJWWrJLVD2pp8GgvuHPoeIxpfVN7pVGmU9LDjP94ho2pfbctQ24qQVgw0HUxrv6K5gtW6A83KQxh48jDzLdBeUL)

### Explanation

```r
"^(<(?1)*>)(?1)*$" = regex for balanced <> with no other characters
^ # match a start of the string
  ( # start of expression 1
    < # open <>
       (?1)* # optional repeat of any number of expression 1 (recursive)
  # allows match for parentheses like (()()())(()) where ?1 is (\\((?1)*\\))
    > # close <>
  ) # end of expression 1
  (?1)* # optional repeat of any number of expression 1
$ # end of string

function(n)
  sort(
    grep("^(<(?1)*>)(?1)*$", # search for regular expression matching open and close brackets
      apply(
        expand.grid(rep(list(60:62),2*n)) # generate 3^(2n) 60,61,62 combinations
      ,1,intToUtf8) # turn into all 3^(2n) combinations of "<","=",">"
    ,,T,T) # return the values that match the regex, so "=" gets ignored
  ) # sort them
```

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 107 bytes

Usual recursive approach.

-1 thanks @Giuseppe

```r
f=function(n,x=0:1)`if`(n,sort(unique(unlist(Map(f,n-1,lapply(seq(x),append,x=x,v=0:1))))),intToUtf8(x+40))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEWvM4MjpNCFFHoEd@q6pWZgIEzSZCrRy8fo23ze4r/cGs986GYSFZTq7KYBF@GlS4nZ4FDZD98nSDG4rgmY9DxQWFMKbyh@h4rUxeuz3yu9/okfJGq3eDe@QD2NDrE9/GYxy8cDI7hpxPYF)

Comment: ah, I was trying to find a `Map` golf but couldn't wrap my head around it. I'm not convinced `parse` + `eval` is going to work since `()()` and the like throw errors.

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>36 35</s> 37 bytes

```
{"()"(|/'0>+\'1-2*)_(x=+/')#+!2|&2*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6pW0tBU0qjRVzew045RN9Q10tKM16iw1dZX11TWVjSqUTPSqqjl4kpTMAYA46cJ8Q==)

`+!2|&2*x` all binary vectors of length 2*n

`(x=+/')#` only those that sum to n

`(|/0>+\'1-2*)_` only those whose partial sums, treating 0/1 as 1/-1, are nowhere negative

`"()"` use 0/1 as indices in this string

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>91</s> <s>88</s> <s>84</s> 81 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and sorted({a[:i]+'()'+a[i:]for a in f(n-1)for i in range(n)})or['']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxCsMwDEbhvafQZovQoYUshpzEeFBw3AqS30H1UkrP7uKp4@Pjne/2rLj3XpZdjjULIYAEmV7V2pb9R2LQNDnPbpKoIZVqJKSg4nG98UgdaYLH5sFfrhadS30I/jJzuNBpijZO7j8)

<sub>-3 bytes thanks to pizzapants184</sub>

Comment: Also works in Python 3, I think

Comment: You can replace `set(...)` with a set comprehension (`{...}`) for -3 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxCsMwDEbhvafQZovQoYUshpzEeFBw3AqS30H1UkrP7uKp4@Pjne/2rLj3XpZdjjULIYAEmV7V2pb9R2LQNDnPbpKoIZVqJKSg4nG98UgdaYLH5sFfrhadS30I/jJzuNBpijZO7j8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„()©s·ãʒ®õ:õQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//@KAnigpwqlzwrfDo8qSwq7DtTrDtVH//zM) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9vc2FiaWX/N0ZOPyIgLT4gIj9O/@KAnigpwqlzwrfDo8qSwq7DtTrDtVH/fSz/Mw).

**Explanation:**

```python
„()            # Push string "()"
   ©           # Store it in the register without popping
    s·         # Swap to get the (implicit) input, and double it
      ã        # Cartesian product that many times
       ʒ       # Filter it by:
        ®      #  Push the "()" from the register
         õ:    #  Infinite replacement with an empty string
           õQ  #  And only keep those which are empty after the infinite replacement
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 114 bytes

```c
f(n,x,s,a,i){char b[99]={};n*=2;for(x=1<<n;x--;s|a<0||puts(b))for(s=a=i=0;i<n;)a|=s+=2*(b[n-i]=41-(x>>i++&1))-81;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzNioMwFIXX@hRZDUnjBS1dTIm3rzGL0kXMNJ0L9lqSCIL66k11O5vD4Ts/Dh7O5ewlV1MVK1uRmt2fDaK7ns83nFfDBzwaPwQ5YdO2bCYAExfb1svyGlOUnVJ7GtEiYW1oqyi7YNR4PMjuykA3PDUgp8uFtP5qlILvxqyZOImnJZZKzGWxXQi5I8LGCGrxtKnWqiwKL0mZsgj3NAYWtSnX/Ha@t4@Y4YcHoOerJ0cJtvk/4kd2iQaG37vrbbC7/wA)

Should work for n <= 15.

#### Explanation

```c
f(n,x,s,a,i){
  char b[99]={};   // Output buffer initialized with zeros.
  n*=2;            // Double n.
  for(x=1<<n;x--;  // Loop from x=2**n-1 to 0, x is a bit field
                   // where 1 represents '(' and 0 represents ')'.
                   // This guarantees lexicographical order.
      s|a<0||puts(b))  // Print buffer if s==0 (as many opening as
                       // closing parens) and a>=0 (number of open
                       // parens never drops below zero).
    for(s=a=i=0;i<n;)  // Loop from i=0 to n-1, note that we're
                       // traversing the bit field right-to-left.
      a|=              // a is the or-sum of all intermediate sums,
                       // it becomes negative whenever an intermediate
                       // sum is negative.
        s+=            // s is the number of closing parens minus the
                       // number of opening parens.
                        x>>i++&1   // Isolate current bit and inc i.
                    41-(        )  // ASCII code of paren, a one bit
                                   // yields 40 '(', a zero bit 41 ')'.
             b[n-i]=               // Store ASCII code in buffer.
          2*(                    )-81;  // 1 for ')' and -1 for '(' since
                                        // we're going right-to-left.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
ç>i<)á Ôke/<>
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=5z5pPCnhINRrZS88Pg==&input=MwotUg==)

---

### Explanation

```
ç                 :Input times repeat the following string
 >i<              :  ">" prepended with "<"
    )             :End repeat
     á            :Get unique permutations
       Ô          :Reverse
        k         :Remove any that return true (non-empty string)
         e/<>     :  Recursively replace Regex /<>/
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n<1?['']:(0...n).flat_map{|w|f[n-1].map{|x|x.insert w,'()'}}|[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/G0D5aXT3WSsNAT08vT1MvLSexJD43saC6prwmLTpP1zBWD8yrqKnQy8wrTi0qUSjXUdfQVK@trYmOrf0P0memCVNToBBdoZMWXRELlAEA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>112</s> 102 bytes

This is heavily based on [nwellnhof's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175419/58563).

```javascript
f=(n,i)=>i>>2*n?'':(g=(o,k)=>o[2*n]?s|m<0?'':o:g('()'[m|=s+=k&1||-1,k&1]+o,k/2))(`
`,i,m=s=0)+f(n,-~i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBDoIwEAXQPQexM1IU0BVx4CCEBIK0qdCOscZV49VrXRpXk7z//9ym1@Tnh7k/C8fXJUZF4KRBak3b1nvXCdGAJmC5JuM@0dD5YC/lN@FGgwAUvQ3kc1p3VQhFJdMd8rQ41ogwZqM00pKnEnOVnhdvg3Fm53lbDhtrUJB62a@c/uSMGD8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 42 bytes

```
{grep {!S:g/\(<~~>*\)//},[X~] <( )>xx$_*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAoVox2CpdP0bDpq7OTitGU1@/Vic6oi5WwUZDQdOuokIlXsuo9n9BaYmCHlBXWn6RgqGenvF/AA)

Uses a recursive regex. Alternative substitution: `S/[\(<~~>\)]*//`

**38 bytes** with 0 and 1 as open/close symbols:

```
{grep {!S:g/0<~~>*1//},[X~] ^2 xx$_*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq9KLVAoVox2Cpd38Cmrs5Oy1Bfv1YnOqIuViHOSKGiQiVey6j2f0FpiYIeUEdafpGCoZ6e8X8A)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                        }  # Anonymous block
                              <( )>         # List "(", ")"
                                   xx$_*2   # repeated 2n times
                         [X~]  # Cartesian product with string concat
                               # yields all strings of length 2n
                               # consisting of ( and )
 grep {                },  # Filter strings
        S:g/             # Globally replace regex match
            \(           #   literal (
              <~~>       #   whole regex matched recursively
                  *      #   zero or more times
                   \)    #   literal )
                     //  # with empty string
       !                 # Is empty string?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>214, 184</strike> 136 bytes

```
func[n][g: func[b n][either n = length? b[if not error? try[load b][print b]return 0][g append copy b"["n g append copy b"]"n]]g""2 * n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY0xCsMwEAR7v2K5MmAISSpD8B/SHios62QbzEkccuHXKyLp3M1sMWsS6kcCuy4ONR46szpeBvzQo4lsZRWD4o1ddCnrCM9bhKYCMUs2otjJe5oCvONsm5YGJuUwxb3VMOUsGjCnfMITk@K6OVLnFqIHbu2zRjy7f4j6vqcu4nHxV/0C)

Uses Jo King's approach. Finds all possilble arrangements of brackes using recursion (they are generated in lexicographic order) and print it if the arrangement evaluates as a valid block.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

*-2 bytes with angle brackets*

```perl
s/<(?R)*>//gr||say for glob'{<,>}'x2x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79Y30bDPkhTy05fP72opqY4sVIhLb9IIT0nP0m92kbHrla9wqhCJf7/f0MuIy5jLpN/@QUlmfl5xf918/7r@prqGRgaAAA)

Port of my Perl 6 answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 50 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
11
+%1`1
<$'¶$`>
Gm`^(?<-1>(<)*>)*$(?(1).)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLkMvQkEtb1TDBkMtGRf3QNpUEOy733IQ4DXsbXUM7DRtNLTtNLRUNew1DTT3N//@NAQ) Uses `<>`s. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1
11
```

Double the result.

```
+%1`1
<$'¶$`>
```

Enumerate all of the 2²ⁿ 2n-bit binary numbers, mapping the digits to `<>`.

```
Gm`^(?<-1>(<)*>)*$(?(1).)
```

Keep only balanced sequences. This uses a balanced parentheses trick discovered by @MartinEnder.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [ChartZBelatedly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/chartz-belatedly)! (Use a better fixed-point built-in.)

```
ḤØ(ṗœṣØ(F$ÐLÐḟ
```

A monadic Link accepting \$n\$ that yields a list of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4bikw5go4bmXxZPhuaPDmChGJMOQTMOQ4bif/8OHWf//NA)** (footer formats the list as lines.)

#### How?

```
ḤØ(ṗœṣØ(F$ÐLÐḟ - Link: integer, n
 Ø(            - literal ['(', ')']
Ḥ              - double (n)
   ṗ           - Cartesian power -> all length 2n lists of '(' and/or ')' (already sorted)
            Ðḟ - filter discard if:
          ÐL   -   repeat until a fixed point is reached applying:
         $     -     last two links as a monad, f(current, initially proposed):
    œṣ         -       split at:
      Ø(       -         literal ['(', ')']
        F      -       flatten
                   } -> empty list if balanced (only empty lists are falsey)
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4bikw5go4bmXxZPhuaPDmChGJMOQTMOQ4bif/8OHWf//NA) as `ƬṪ$` can be replaced with `ÐL`

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly - Ah, I golfed my way from something that then transposed and head-ed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 80 bytes

```hs
f n=[x|x<-mapM("()"<$f)[1..2*n],0:y<-[scanr(\b->(sum[2|b>'(']-1+))0x],all(>=0)y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzza6oqbCRjc3scBXQ0lDU8lGJU0z2lBPz0grL1bHwKrSRje6ODkxr0gjJknXTqO4NDfaqCbJTl1DPVbXUFtT06AiVicxJ0fDztZAszL2f25iZp4tyKx4hYLSkuCSIp88lTQFk/8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
Ø+xŒ!QÄAƑ>ṪƊ$Ƈ=1ịØ(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//w5greMWSIVHDhEHGkT7huarGiiTGhz0x4buLw5go/8OHKy/igqzFkuG5mP//Mw)

Output clarified over TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 84 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,s='')=>n?f(n-=.5,s+'[')+f(n,s+']'):[...s].some(t=>(n+=t<']'?1:-1)<0)|n?'':s+`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZclLDoIwEADQPReZmRQa8bNpGHoQQgLB1mhgapzGlXevujRu37vNz1mXx/WeG0nnUEpklFoZgLgXH1EatqdaDQxAJn7PwAjkBmutjlbTFjBzj2I4d5/xrWta6nb0Eg/g1EzVVJYkmtZg13TBiHui6lcOf3IkKm8)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 90 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,s='')=>n?f(n-=.5,s+'[')+f(n,s+']'):eval("try{eval(s.split``+``),s+`\n`}catch(_){''}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYrLCsIwEADvfkYvu0vaHHxchNQPUXFDbLQSktINBSn99vi4ibdhZh52suLGfshNTNeuFG8w1mIAyLTx4DE2Ru9qUXAEUv7TFJyB9t1kA1Z5fM5fEi1D6DOzYqb3w6fIi7PZ3fFCM8BSUXEpSgqdDumGHtdEq1@z@TNbovIC)

Is it an array?