# Find the number of parenthesis combinations

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, permutations, balanced-string

For example, given 3 sets of parenthesis, you have:

```
()()()
((()))
()(())
(())()
(()())
```

= 5 possible combinations.

**Challenge**

Program must:

• Take 1 number as an input

• Return one output, the number of possible combinations of parenthesis sets

Shortest number of bytes wins

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. I'd recommend you explain what a "valid" parenthesis set is. Check out some of the questions in the [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string) tag for some good definitions

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66127/58563)?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Catalan Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66127/53748)?

Comment: Heh, ninja'd in a comment, that's another level.

Comment: FWIW One interpretation is that the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ Catalan number is the count of the number of expressions containing \$n\$ pairs of parentheses which are correctly matched. So this will almost certainly get closed as a duplicate - don't let this put you off asking more questions though @CamdenWeaver.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do we already have a challenge where all patterns must be printed/returned?

Comment: @Arnauld we have a restricted version - [Parentheses sequences in lexicographical order](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/175381/53748).